# How to configure Tor as service on windows?

Tags: windows-10, proxy, services, tor, socks5

I just want to have tor proxy server up and running all the time on my windows 10 PC. Tor browser doesn't fit my needs. So I'd like to be able to connect anything I want via socks5 proxy.

It was so easy to set it up on mac. But on windows -- I'm stuck. I tried to google, but could not find a clear, plain way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install Tor as a Windows service, assuming it's installed in folder
`C:\Tor`, you need to first create its `torrc` configuration file,
for example:

```
echo( > C:\Tor\torrc
```

To test if the service with the settings file will start correctly:

```
C:\Tor\tor.exe -f "C:\Tor\torrc"
```

Now to install the Tor service:

```
C:\Tor\tor.exe --service install -options -f "C:\Tor\torrc"
```

To start and stop the service, use the following commands
(or set it to automatically start in the Services applet):

```
C:\Tor\tor.exe --service start
C:\Tor\tor.exe --service stop
```

To remove the service:

```
C:\Tor\tor.exe --service stop
C:\Tor\tor.exe --service remove
```

By default, the Tor service listens on port 9050,
which can be checked by the command:

```
netstat -aon | findstr ":9050"
```

But it's up to you to set each internet browser or application to use the
Tor Socks5 proxy, found at `localhost` port 9050.

For more details, see the article
[How to install Tor and create Tor hidden service on Windows](https://miloserdov.org/?p=1839&PageSpeed=noscript).

---

Here is a small test I did with the latest version.
The folder layout of the Tor folder has changed, but the rest works the same:

[image]

Comment: C:\Tor\tor.exe -f "C:\Tor\torrc" returns an empty line. What does it mean? Well, tor.exe with a bullshit parameter returns an empty line too. Can you try it yourself first? Actually I've seen the page you linked. It seemed to me absolutely outdated

Comment: I have tried it without the `-f` and all seems to work fine. The configuration file in my answer is empty; to populate it see the above link and the Tor documentation.

Comment: It's really strange. Tor exe shows no output. But the proxy works. I tried both powershell and cmd. Why? :) https://ibb.co/BNTh0cN

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Tor, but installing it as a Windows service didn't really work
then I stumbled across nssm, downloaded, copied 64bit version to Windows\System32

nssm install  an input field opens
or
nssm install   []

I then installed Tor Browser as a service, and it worked on the first try

nssm install TORWIN32 tor.exe --service install -options "C:\Users\Markus\OneDrive\Desktop\Tor-Browser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc"
https://www.nssm.cc/download

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: When recommending a third party product, its good practice to declare your affiliation to it.